# TFS/Azure DevOps - Edit a work item field during Pull Request

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, workflow, devops, pull-request

Good morning,
I'm sorry to bother you,

In Azure DevOps 2019 / TFS, as it is possible to autocomplete a work item when validating a pull request.

I would like to know if it would also be possible to add a field to the pull request that would modify the corresponding fields in the linked work items.
In our workflow, a field would have to be filled in during this step (from "Active" to "Resolved") of the pull request and I don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in pull request by default. But a similar user voice is under review, you can vote it and add your comment:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html

Comment: If you have time, can you check my other question right here ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995072/azure-devops-cant-get-deployment-status-to-board

Thanks you !