# Azure Devops - Can't get deployment status to board

Tags: tfs, deployment, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment

I would like to integrate the deployment control into my work items but to do so the Microsoft site recommends to:

> Select the "Preview: Report deployment status to Boards" option and
>   configure the stages and deployment types
>
> [image: Screen from Microsoft Website with Boards]

...but on my Azure DevOps Server, I don't have this choice. What can I do to get this choice or to enable the Deployment control in my work items / bug items?

Here is my view:

[image: Screen from my Azure DevOps Server without Board choice]
From : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops

EDIT for more informations :

When I try to add the deployment control tool in my work item XML, I get this "error" : Cannot create work item control of type "DeploymentsControl". Legacy extensions are no longer supported in new work item form.

[image: Cannot create work item control of type "DeploymentsControl". Legacy extensions are no longer supported in new work item form.]

Answer (score 1):

> The release deployments control currently works with classic release
>   pipelines and with **Azure DevOps Services** (cloud) only.

Since you are using **Azure DevOps Server** (on-premise), this feature is not supported yet. You may submit a user voice at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22

Comment: Is there anything else I can add to my work item template that might be relevant to deployments?

Comment: No default way, unless you develop your own [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=azure-devops).